# How to map IQueryable to GenericList either using Auto Mapper or different way

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper, n-tier-architecture

I have list result output of LINQ Query from multiple joins with various classes.
this is happening in data access layer and I need to convert it to business object list

```
namespace App.Business.Entities
{
  public class GetAllFunction_VM
   {
    public GetAllFunction_VM()
    { }

    [Required]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    public int Hierarchy_Level { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string ParentFunctionName { get; set; }

    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public int FunctionInControllerID { get; set; }

    public int ActionID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public int FunctionInActionID { get; set; }

   }
 }
```

### Business Object

```
public List<FunctionNavigation_VM> GetAllFunctions()
    {
        List<FunctionNavigation_VM> FunctionNavigationListObject = new List<FunctionNavigation_VM>();

        try
        {

            using (var _uow = new FunctionsNavigation_UnitOfWork())
            {
                var entities = (from functionNavigation in _uow.Sys_Nav_Functions_Repository.GetAll()
                                join functionHierarchy in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionHierarchy.Function_ID
                                join functionNavigation_b in _uow.Sys_Nav_Functions_Repository.GetAll() on functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID equals functionNavigation_b.Function_ID
                                        into tmp from functionNavigation_b in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join functionInController in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionInController_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInController.Function_ID
                                join functionController in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionController_Repository.GetAll() on functionInController.ControllerID equals functionController.ControllerID
                                join functionInAction in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionInAction_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInAction.Function_ID
                                join functionAction in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionAction_Repository.GetAll() on functionInAction.ActionID equals functionAction.ActionID
                                select new
                                {
                                    functionNavigation.Function_ID,
                                    FunctionName = functionNavigation.Title,
                                    functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level,
                                    ParentID = functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID,
                                    ParentFunctionName = functionNavigation_b.Title,
                                    functionController.ControllerID,
                                    functionController.ControllerName,
                                    functionInController.FunctionInControllerID,
                                    functionAction.ActionID,
                                    functionAction.ActionName,
                                    functionInAction.FunctionInActionID
                                }
                               );

                //Map Data Entity to Business Entity
                //need help here... Auto Mapper 
              return FunctionNavigationListObject ;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Automapper can just do that based on convention. As long as you make a class that is similar to your anonymous object. However, if you are doing huge joins, it's probably better to do it in sql, and use the `context.Database.ExecuteQuery<T>()` and make use of that auto object mapping there.

Comment: *"//need help here..."*, what did you try already? Automapper isn't particularly hard to use...

Comment: Side note - do NOT just catch any exception and return `null`.  You lose ANY indicaction of what the error is.  If you're not going to do anything about it here, just let it bubble up and handle it in higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

Sincle you're already generating the fields for your desired result type, just use that as your projected type:

```
public List<FunctionNavigation_VM> GetAllFunctions()
{
    using (var _uow = new FunctionsNavigation_UnitOfWork())
    {
        var entities = (from functionNavigation in _uow.Sys_Nav_Functions_Repository.GetAll()
                        join functionHierarchy in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionHierarchy.Function_ID
                        join functionNavigation_b in _uow.Sys_Nav_Functions_Repository.GetAll() on functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID equals functionNavigation_b.Function_ID
                                into tmp from functionNavigation_b in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join functionInController in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionInController_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInController.Function_ID
                        join functionController in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionController_Repository.GetAll() on functionInController.ControllerID equals functionController.ControllerID
                        join functionInAction in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionInAction_Repository.GetAll() on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInAction.Function_ID
                        join functionAction in _uow.Sys_Nav_FunctionAction_Repository.GetAll() on functionInAction.ActionID equals functionAction.ActionID
                        select new FunctionNavigation_VM
                        {
                            functionNavigation.Function_ID,
                            FunctionName = functionNavigation.Title,
                            functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level,
                            ParentID = functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID,
                            ParentFunctionName = functionNavigation_b.Title,
                            functionController.ControllerID,
                            functionController.ControllerName,
                            functionInController.FunctionInControllerID,
                            functionAction.ActionID,
                            functionAction.ActionName,
                            functionInAction.FunctionInActionID
                        }
                       );

      return entities.ToList(); ;
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the projection to create `FunctionNavigation_VM` objects and remove the try/catch block since it's very rarely a good idea to swallow exceptions.  Either do something about it or just let it bubble up and handle it at different layers.